# Move different images across a canvas on a timer/delay

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas, html5-canvas

I wish to be able to move some images say 5/6 across the canvas. The position of the image will obviously change each time, simulating basic animation. The images will be on a timer/ delay so that they move every second or so. Is there a function that i can create so that i dont have to repeat the same code over and over again for the images. Also it would be good if the images were preloaded but im unsure on how to manipulate the image once it has been preloaded.

If there was also a way of using requestAnimationFrame instead of setTimeout then that would be even better.

Heres my current code:

```
 window.addEventListener("load", eventWindowLoaded, false);
        function eventWindowLoaded () {

        images = new Array();
        images[0] = "images/1.png";
        images[1] = "images/2.png";
        images[2] = "images/3.png";
        images[3] = "images/4.png";
        images[4] = "images/5.png";

        imageObjs = [];

        for(var i = 0; i <= 4; i++){
            var imageObj = new Image();
            imageObj.src = images[i];
            imageObjs.push(imageObj);
        }       
drawFrame();
}

function drawFrame () { 



        setTimeout(function() {
        image = new Image();
        image.onload = function() {
            ctx.drawImage(imageObjs[0], 0, 0);
        }
        image.src = "images/1.png";
        }, 200);


        setTimeout(function () {
        image2 = new Image();

        image2.onload = function() {
            ctx.drawImage(imageObjs[1], 200, 0);
        };
        image2.src = "images/2.png";
    }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You expressed interest in having code do the following:**

- Preload all images.
- Move images across the canvas.
- Use an animation loop function so code is not repeated.
- Use requestAnimationFrame instead of setTimeout for efficiency.

**Here's example code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;


var images=[];
images.push({x:20,y:200,moveX:5,maxX:250,delay:100,nextTime:0,url:'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/cars1.png'});
images.push({x:20,y:30,moveX:10,maxX:100,delay:500,nextTime:0,url:'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/sun.png'});
var imageCount=images.length;
for(var n=0;n<images.length;n++){ 
  var i=images[n];
  i.img=new Image();
  i.img.onload=start;
  i.img.src=i.url;
}
function start(){
  if(--imageCount>0){return;}
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}


function animate(time){
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);   
  var needsRedrawing=false;
  for(var n=0;n<images.length;n++){
    var i=images[n];
    if(time>i.nextTime){
      if(i.x+i.moveX<i.maxX){
        i.x+=i.moveX;
        i.nextTime+=i.delay;
        needsRedrawing=true;
      }
    }
  }
  if(needsRedrawing){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
    for(var n=0;n<images.length;n++){
      var i=images[n];
      ctx.drawImage(i.img,i.x,i.y);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: Is it possible to have images alternating as they move? e.g. the car moves 5px, then it changes to the sun which moves 5px and then back to the car again? So there would only be one image on the screen at any time

Comment: Sure! You can use maxX to control if an image is moving or is stopped.  The images move until they reach maxX and then they stop. So, start the sun moving by setting its maxX larger then its x. You can test if it has reached its maxX (and is therefore stopped) using: `if(i.x>=i.maxX)`. When the sun has stopped, then you can start the car image moving by setting its maxX larger than its x ... and repeat as desired ... Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thanks, I think I've got it. So when the first image has reached its maxX could I simply just pop() it from the array and begin the second image from where the first one finished? And so on? So there would only ever be one image on display but it would be a continual animation